# Launch dummy Rest endpoint from Test class

Tags: java, rest, automated-tests, cucumber-java

Assume an API exposed by the server contains a callback url passed by client. To test the functional flow of server api, from the test class (cucumber) how can that dummy REST end point be launched so that server can invoke it as part of the flow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple http server that is supplied with JDK (at least with Oracle JDK and OpenJDK). Here is the example:

```java
package so.task;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

public class BackCall {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress("master-host", 11223), 1);
        server.createContext("/test", new HttpHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
                System.out.println(httpExchange.getRequestMethod());
            }
        });
        server.start();
    }
}
```

So that you can implement your handler in the way you could check if there was a callback and examine all the properties of that request that carried that call back (i.e. if that was a GET request).

It is important to set socket address using the host name that your remote service would be using for a call back.